# Struts2, problem with 2 variables in one address

Tags: jsp, variables, struts2

I'm using struts2, now in my jsp file i've got 2 variables:

```
${server_address}
${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

Now i want to connect it in my tag:

```
<s:form action="%{server_address}%{pageContext.request.contextPath}/actionName.action">
```

But generated output looks like that:

```
<form method="post" action="http://10.0.0.5:8088/actionName.action" name="actionName" id="actionName">
```

There is no contextPath... How can i connect this two variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<s:set var="baseUrl">${server_address}${pageContext.request.contextPath}</s:set>

<s:set var="actionUrl">${baseUrl}<s:url action="actionName"/></s:set>

<s:form action="%{actionUrl}">
`enter code here`...
</s:form>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! 
<s:set var="sth">${server_address}${attr.request['javax.servlet.forward.context_path']}</s:set>

Answer (score 2):

Use `${pageContext}` instead of `%{pageContext}`. The `pageContext` isn't available in Struts2's scope, but in JSP's scope.

Comment: Ok, that's part of solution i need. 

Now how can i add ${pageContext} to action in form above? 

I've got this exception if i use $ instead of %: According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions

Comment: Sorry, I don't do Struts2. Without going into code detail, I'd say that you basically need to grab the `HttpServletRequest` somehow in your Struts2 bean and then delegate it. As a completely different advice, use the HTML `<base>` tag for this.

Comment: Ok, i found it. ${attr.request['javax.servlet.forward.context_path']} but still, how can i connect 2 or more string variable to new one or how can i add those 2 variable to my s:form so it will works ?

Answer (score 0):

In Struts 2.3 worked

```
            <c:set var="businessActionMapping" value="foo" scope="session"/>
            <s:form action="%{#session.businessActionMapping}"
```

You might have need to set altSyntax=TRUE in struts.properties